# rubber tyre at the end of a chain

Tags: meaning

In a novel, two men speak about a good-looking lawyer in Antigua island
One says to the other :

> When you said she was a lawyer I was thinking of someone playing on a rubber tyre at the end of a chain.

I must admit I'm not sure of the pun intended here. Tyres mounted on chain may be used as a swing of sort, but what else could it be ? Meaning she's a *dog* ?

Comment: Please provide context— what is the name of the novel? What is the surrounding dialogue? This text seems to appear in only one other place on a web search, except the other says the setting is Guadaloupe.

Comment: It is from *False Nine* by Phillip Kerr https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ZTa5CgAAQBAJ&pg=PT135&lpg=PT135&dq=When+you+said+she+was+a+lawyer+I+was+thinking+of+someone+playing+on+a+rubber+tyre+at+the+end+of+a+chain&source=bl&ots=MmnSGXNH0H&sig=xr_YZJHhT5HWLpJIhHDKgzUwSLs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGgrithr7TAhWCL8AKHYtMCXEQ6AEIMTAC#v=onepage&q=When%20you%20said%20she%20was%20a%20lawyer%20I%20was%20thinking%20of%20someone%20playing%20on%20a%20rubber%20tyre%20at%20the%20end%20of%20a%20chain&f=false

Answer (score 2):

> 'That’s her. That’s the lady lawyer I was talking about.'
>    'Man, that is a fine-looking woman.'
>   'You think?'
>   'When you said she was a lawyer I was thinking of someone playing on a rubber tyre at the end of a chain. But that lady is hot, boss.'
>   Everton was right. The woman had more curves than a bag full of footballs.

from **False Nine** by Philip Kerr

With the additional information above there are enough textual clues to understand that the words "someone playing on a rubber tyre at the end of a chain" refers to a girl who is young or looks young, whose body is not developed, boy-like.  He means he assumed that this lawyer was a woman who wasn't physically beautiful and didn't have a lot of prospects to marry well so she worked hard and became a lawyer to be able to provide an income for herself.  But, actually, the lady lawyer is very attractive (as well as intelligent).

Comment: Kind of a stupid analogy, since most lawyers are not preteens or what not. But it's Phillip Kerr.

Comment: I agree the analogy was a little inaccessible which is why it became a question, although it's not uncommon to hear women referred to as girls in other phrases.  I don't think he meant to imply she was a preteen, merely that he had envisioned her as a woman whose undeveloped body would remind someone of a girl.  I suppose if he had said rail or beanpole or twiggy it would have been easier to process, but these are equally metaphorical.